# Can't find the .exe of my game after I built it with unity, why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I finished a tutorial of a game, then when I built the game to be exported on windows, mac etc..... , I couldn't find the .exe of the game itself even after I have done it as the tutorial says It works perfectly on I play it on unity itself for testing. Any Idea ?

Comment: At the top of unity it says what build type aka WebGL, Windows/Linux, are you sure you are building it, not just running it in the editor? As it will build it to wherever you told it to build to..

Comment: You can actually build your game using `Build Settings` window (`File->Build Settings->Pc/Mac/Linux->Build`)

Comment: I did the same process but the problem is still there

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your build settings and the folder you built into? You can use [imgur](https://www.imgur.com) or something.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Pxd8s6q
@TehMightyPotato

Comment: The folder you posted is definitely not the folder you built to. There is a subfolder in there called `build`. Check in there.

Comment: Also you have `Server Build` checked. You only use that for dedicated server builds in multiplayer. Uncheck that if your game is singleplayer.

Comment: okay I will try something]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

this will put the folder on your desktop, the exe should be inside this folder. you can also put it somewhere else by using the navigation window in the last image. you might want to build it inside a folder as well.

Comment: thats what happened on the tutorial, but on my part the .exe name, company was determined inside unity from player settings .... so when i try to save the build it gave me only the choice to where to save the file

Answer (score 1):

try building it on the folder where the project is located

Comment: still the same problem 
@Donat